# How to allow users to draw path on google map?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook, google-maps

I'm developing a Facebook app which allow my users to draw their wanted path on Google map for their marathon purpose. I'm gonna use mySQL database records to create some fixed points  (some places according to their latitude and longtitude) and there will be a start and a end point. So whenever a fix point is clicked, a line will be drawn/plot between the previous point clicked and the current point clicked.

Do you guys know how I can achieve this ? Links, tutorials, codes, comments and references are all welcomed. Just start learning Google maps today therefore I hope I can get useful and knowledgeable helps. Thanks a million guys.

Language used is PHP, javascript is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps API has a [Drawing Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools) which allows you to do exactly that. Load it in, put the control up, if you want limit it to only polylines, and then when you get a completed event post it back to your server.